# How to convert sql server field size to vb.net (My need is to specify parameter size against sql server field)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I would like to know is there any size difference when specifying parameter size in vb.net versus a sql server field.

`Varchar(50)` in sql server and `SqlDbType.VarChar(???)`.

Is there any conversion happen from sql field size to vb.net or it will be same as in sql server.

Comment: Its not clear what you mean. Are you talking about parameters that are used when executing a query or do you mean running a create statement from an application (ie. `create table xxx(`.?

Comment: @Igor
For example if there is a table in sql named **Person_Detail** And inside this table there is a column named **PersonName** and its Datatype is **Varchar(50)**. So i want to know what parameter size should i enter when inserting data in **Person_Detail** table through parameterized query. Like `sql_Command.Parameters.Add("@PName", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = "John"`  OR What.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### [SqlParameter.Size Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> ...
>
> For variable-length data types, Size describes the maximum amount of data to transmit to the server. For example, for a Unicode string value, Size could be used to limit the amount of data sent to the server to the first one hundred characters.
>
> If not explicitly set, the size is inferred from the actual size of the specified parameter value.
>
> ...

Ideally though you should set the parameter sizes if you know them or if you know they are constrained.